# SO_WIFI_STATUS socket option in Linux

Tags: linux, sockets, wifi, hostapd

Could someone shed some light on the SO_WIFI_STATUS socket option - I encountered it in the hostapd nl80211 driver code. I could find it's declaration in the /usr/include/asm-generic/socket.h file but could not find any relevant documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The explanation and patch: [`RFC] net: add wireless TX status socket option`

http://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg176403.html

A sample application:

http://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg176415.html

The references:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=SO_WIFI_STATUS

If you could not find it in your `/usr/include/asm-generic/socket.h`, it's because your kernel is too old. In mine:

```
jbm@sumo:~$ grep -n SO_WIFI_STATUS /usr/include/asm-generic/socket.h
68:#define SO_WIFI_STATUS       41
69:#define SCM_WIFI_STATUS  SO_WIFI_STATUS
jbm@sumo:~$ uname -a
Linux sumo 4.3.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.3.3-7 (2016-01-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```